# Laravel querying model relationships

Tags: model, laravel, relationship

Is there a way to do something similar like this?

```
Picture::with('gallery')->where('gallery.path', $galleryPath)->first();
```

It should search a record, but the query will be applied on its relationship.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Laravel 4.1:

```
$picture = Picture::whereHas('gallery', function($q) use ($galleryPath)
{
    $q->where('path', $galleryPath);

})->first();
```

Laravel 4:

```
$picture = Picture::with(array('gallery' => function($q) use ($galleryPath)
 {
   $q->where('path', $galleryPath); 
 }))->first();
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( Even Gallery::has('pictures')->get() returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [Eager Load Contraints](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

You can specify the condition on your relation using function callback e.g

```
Picture::with(array('gallery' => function($query) 
 {
   $query->where('path', $galleryPath); 
 }))->get();
```

Comment: Your query will return all picture records, and eager load and join a gallery record, where the path matches. What it should do, is load only those picture records, that have have a gallery that matches a path. You see the difference?

Comment: Hmmm if you are using Laravel 4.1 you can use the `whereHas` method that should return picture records that have at least one gallery with the specified condition.